# Typescript: Cannot find name Predicate

Tags: typescript

I've created this file `Perdicate.ts`:

```
export interface Predicate {
    not(): Predicate;
}
```

Into `Query.ts`:

```
export interface Query {
    getWhere(): Predicate;
}
```

I'm getting this compiler error:

```
message: 'Cannot find name 'Predicate'.'
```

`Query.ts` and `Predicate.ts` are located in the same folder.

Comment: You need to import it. `import { Predicate } from './Perdicate';` (sic)

Answer (score 3):

You need also to import the interface `Predicate` into the file interface `Query`

```
import { Predicate } from './predicate'; // Consider your `Predicate` is in the `predicate.ts`

export interface Query {
    getWhere(): Predicate;
}
```